# Python return "None" prevents following for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, tweepy

I'm using Tweepy to stream tweets. I'm trying to filter out retweeted content using the retweeted_status identifier in the json file. 
I want the for loop to execute after the empty return on the line before it, but it doesn't seem to work- nothing gets printed out. The script seems to stop after the if statement:

```
class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):


        def on_status(self, status):
                #these variable split out the data from the outputted json
                text = status.text
                name = status.user.screen_name
                id_str = status.id_str

#This if argument ensures that if there is retweeted status then None is returned
                if hasattr (status, 'retweeted_status'):
                        return
                for url in status.entities['urls']:

                        print (text, name, (url['expanded_url']), file=open("results.txt", "a"))
```

Comment: "I want the for loop to execute", and  "return statement" do not go together in the same sentence.

Comment: Are you trying to return the text that the for loop is supposed to print? What is the intention of the if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably call another function if the new data from the `on_status` method contains things you want. There is no need to do a continue inside of the `on_status` method because it's not a for loop, unless you create your own for loop and decide to continue based on your own custom business logic.

Under the hood the Tweepy library is calling a inherited(`StreamListener`) method from your custom `StreamListener` called [on_data](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/streaming.py). The only thing you're responsible for is doing something with that data or not.

```
def handle_status_update(status):
    # Handle your custom stuff in here...
    text = status.text
    name = status.user.screen_name
    id_str = status.id_str

    for url in status.entities['urls']:
        print (text, name, (url['expanded_url']), file=open("results.txt", "a"))


class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):


        def on_status(self, status):
            # if not retweeted
            if not hasattr (status, 'retweeted_status'):
                handle_status_update(status)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using return (Which will exit your function completely), you just want to go on to the next iteration of the for loop without printing. Though for that to make sense, your if statement should be inside the for loop.

Replace `return` with `continue` and it should work great. `continue` skips the rest of the for loop and starts on the next value.

If you want an empty line to be printed out before the for loop, then replace `return` with `print()` and that will happen instead.

Comment: i'm getting SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop

Comment: @nmh That's because you're not in a loop.

Comment: @nmh That's why I gave the second example of printing an empty line before the for loop, in case you don't want your if statement to be inside the for loop. What do you expect the return to be doing there?